# Union in parameters changes error behavior

Tags: typescript

I bet this question has been asked before, but sadly have no good search terms.

Changing parameters to a union apparently also enables strict counting of parameters. This can:

a) make dummy parameters required, for no reason at all:

```
// Works.
const f: (...args: [x: string, y: boolean]                         ) => void = (    ) => {};
const g: (...args: [x: string, y: boolean]                         ) => void = (n   ) => {};
const h: (...args: [x: string, y: boolean]                         ) => void = (n, m) => {};
// Still works.
const i: (...args: [x: string, y: boolean] | [x: string, y: symbol]) => void = (    ) => {};
const j: (...args: [x: string, y: boolean] | [x: string, y: symbol]) => void = (n, m) => {};
// Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 1.(2322)
const k: (...args: [x: string, y: boolean] | [x: string, y: symbol]) => void = (n   ) => {};
```

b) allow imho invalid assignments, when there is no union:

```
// Works.
const f: (...args: any[]) => void = (...args: [number, string]                   ) => {};
// Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.(2322)
const g: (...args: any[]) => void = (...args: [number, string] | [string, number]) => {};
```

Why is this the case, and is there a way to enforce either behavior, what the parameters look like being irrelevant?

---

PS: with `strictFunctionTypes`, which is default these days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug.

There is an [open bug about it on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48663).

Comment: Interesting, i thought it would be a more common problem, and a misunderstanding on my side, as this seems to date back quite far, when trying older versions. In the second case, the error would even be desired. However, enabling this by default would e.g. make writing a type for "any function" difficult - `(...args: any[]) => any` wouldn't work anymore.